# Error when calling an R object in a python chunk (R markdown)

Tags: python, r, r-markdown, reticulate

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NGFD.png)I am using the library reticulate to run some python code in RStudio.
The syntax to call an R object in a python chunk is : r.object.
Unfortunatly I have this error message when calling my r.object in the python code portion... (screenshot below). Also I am running my code on an rstudio instance on an amazon cloud (should not pose a problem...)
Do not really understand why...

Thanks in advance for helping :)

You will also find the R code portion that comes right before i run the python chunk [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8609.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what your trying to do, but I can help you read the error.

You can see that the error is coming from line 10 which is this one:

```
for f in r.test_idx.keys():
```

You don't have any object before this line that instantiates r. As far as the code is concerned, `r` does not exist and you are trying to call the `test_idx.keys()` method from the `r` object.

There's actually nothing in the for loop that references anything outside of it.

Are these values defined in the `R` chunks of the code?

If so, can you post the `R` chunks that precede this and I can help further.

Kind Regards

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I am adding the piece of code that comes before this portion in which i define the r object test_idx :)